# parse and rearrange hostnames

Tags: c++, python, perl, awk

Below is a list of hostnames that is stored in a text file.

```
web1.maxi.com
web3.maxi.com
web4.maxi.com
web5.maxi.com
web6.maxi.com
web7.maxi.com
web8.maxi.com
web9.maxi.com
web11.maxi.com
```

for the sake of displaying it shortly it needs to be parsed and rewritten/displayed as

```
web[1,3-9,11].maxi.com
```

can you guys help me on this, any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With perl you can use the [`Set::IntSpan`](https://metacpan.org/module/Set%3a%3aIntSpan) module for compressing the number sequence.

The below solution can handle mixed and unordered site listings.

*infile*

```
web3.maxi.com
web4.maxi.com
web5.maxi.com
mail1.mexi.com
web6.maxi.com
web9.maxi.com
web9.maxi.com

web11.maxi.com
mail3.mexi.com
web7.maxi.com
mail4.mexi.com
mail25.mexi.com      
  mail26.mexi.com
mail27.mexi.com
mail28.mexi.com
  web8.maxi.com
mail29.mexi.com
mail110.mexi.com
web1.maxi.com
```

*parse.pl*

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use Set::IntSpan;
use File::Slurp qw/slurp/;

$str = slurp(\*STDIN);

# Remove redundant whitespace
chop $str;
$str =~ s/^[\t ]+|[\t ]+$//gm;
$str =~ s/\R+/\n/g;

# Copy $str so we can match numbers in it without disturbing the loop
$nums = $str;

# Parse lines in $str in sequence
while($str =~ /^(.*)$/gm) {
  $line = $1;

  # Extract bits before and after number
  ($pre, $post) = $line =~ /([^\d]+)\d+(.*)$/m;

  # Check if its been printed already
  next if $seen{$pre . $post};

  # If not, extract numbers
  @numbers = $nums =~ /$pre(\d+)$post/g;

  print $pre . "[" 
        . Set::IntSpan->new(@numbers)->run_list()
        . "]" . $post;

  $seen{$pre . $post} = 1;
}
```

Run it like this:

```
perl parse.pl < infile
```

Output:

```
web[1,3-9,11].maxi.com
mail[1,3-4,25-29,110].mexi.com
```

The perhaps cryptic `@numbers = $nums =~ /$pre(\d+)$post/g` expands to an array of items matched by the regular expression and saves it in `@numbers`.

Note that this solution loads the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    sites=[x.strip() for x in f]
    ranges=[]
    for x in sites:
        x=x.split(".")
        num=int(x[0][x[0].index("web")+3:])
        if ranges:
            if num-ranges[-1][-1]==1:
                ranges[-1].append(num)
            else:
                ranges.append([num])    
        else:
            ranges.append([num])        
    print ranges
    print "web["+",".join(str(x[0]) if len(x)==1 else str(x[0])+"-"+str(x[-1]) for x in ranges)+"].maxi.com"
```

**output:**

```
[[1], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [11]]
web[1,3-9,11].maxi.com
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on it:

```
#print hosts
lines = open("log.txt").readlines()
numbers = [int(line.split(".")[0][3:]) for line in lines]
out = [[]]
index = 0
for i in xrange(len(numbers) - 1):
    out[index].append(numbers[i])
    if (numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i] != 1):
        out.append( [] )
        index += 1
out[-1].append(numbers[-1])
strings = [str(number[0]) if len(number) == 1 else str(number[0]) + "-" + str(number[-1]) for number in out]
print ",".join(strings)
```

Would be good to change the loop to something more pythonic/functional.